# Update a table based on a results of a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Update a table based on a results of a group by

I've got a tricky update problem I'm trying to solve. There are two tables that contain the same three columns plus additional varied columns, looking like this:

`Table1 {pers_id, loc_id, pos, ... }`

`Table2 {pers_id, loc_id, pos, ... }`

None of the fields are unique. The first two fields collectively identify the records in a table (or tables) as belonging to the same entity. Table1 could have 15 records belonging to an entity, and table2 could have 4 records belonging to the same entity. The third column 'pos' is an index from 0 to whatever, and this is the column that I'm trying to update.

In Table1 and in Table2, the pos column begins at 0, and increments based on user selection, so that in the example (15 records in table1 and 4 records in table2), table1 contains 'pos' values of 0 - 14, and Table2 contains 'pos' values of 0-3.

I want to increment the pos field in Table1 with the results of the count of similar entities in Table2. This is the sql statement that correctly gives me the results from table2:

`select table2.pers_id, table2.loc_id, count(*) as pos_increment from table2 group by table2.pers_id, table2.loc_id;`

The end result of the update, in the example (15 records in table1 and 4 records in table2), would be all records in Table1 of the same entity being incremented by 4 (the result of the specific entity group by). 0 would be changed to 4, 15 to 19, etc.

Is this achievable in a single statement?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to increment the `pos` field the solution is really simple:

```
update table1 t1
set    t1.pos = t1.pos + 
   (select count(1)
    from   table2 t2
    where  t2.pers_id = t1.pers_id
    and    t2.loc_id  = t1.loc_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, you can use MERGE for some of these upadtes and there are ways to relate values between the update and the subselect.  I have done this in the past, but it's tricky and I don't have an existing example.

You can find several examples on this site, some for Oracle and some for other database that will awork with slight modifications.